# Mobile Ads on Facebook for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, ads

Does anyone know if Facebook strips the link that you input when setting up a Mobile App Install ad? Our Mobile App is not integrated with Facebook's SDK so I was hoping to track downloads from our paid ads through the iTunes Connect platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they strip it! You should try with a service between your app and Facebook like [GearAds](http://www.gearads.net) which is useful for your problem